# Android OutOfMemoryError, how to debug using DDMS and track what is causing the memory leak?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, memory-leaks, ddms

I think I am not following the standard general rule for optimizing memory of an android app, and I keep getting OutOfMemoryError, now I am trying to debug and find the source using DDMS in Android Studio, but I have no idea how to read it and how to find which object is taking up the biggest space. Below is my codes.

ChooseLevelActivity

```
public class ChooseLevelActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    ImageView level001, level002, level003, level004, level005;
    int last_level, best_move;
    String best_time, level_selected;
    TextView levelName, bestMove, bestTime, no_level_finished;
    Class <? extends Activity> classVariable;
    Button playBtn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.choose_level);

        level001 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.level001);
        level002 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.level002);
        level003 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.level003);
        level004 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.level004);
        level005 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.level005);

        levelName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.level_name);
        bestMove = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.best_move);
        bestTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.best_time);
        no_level_finished = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.no_level_finished);
        playBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.playBtn);

        // First check if file exists
        File recordFile = getBaseContext().getFileStreamPath("levels.json");
        if (recordFile.exists()) {

            // Get the JSON Object from the data
            JSONObject parent = parseJSONData("levels.json");

            // Array of ImageView
            final ImageView[] levelsArray = {level001, level002, level003, level004, level005};

            // This will store all the values inside "best_move and time" in an element string
            try {
                last_level = parent.getInt("level");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            for(int i = 0; i < last_level; i++) {
                levelsArray[i].setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                levelsArray[i].setOnClickListener(this);
            }

        } else {
            no_level_finished.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            playBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.level001:
                level_selected = "level001";
                classVariable = Level001Activity.class;
                break;
            case R.id.level002:
                level_selected = "level002";
                classVariable = Level002Activity.class;
                break;
            case R.id.level003:
                level_selected = "level003";
                classVariable = Level003Activity.class;
                break;
            case R.id.level004:
                level_selected = "level004";
                classVariable = Level004Activity.class;
                break;
            case R.id.level005:
                level_selected = "level005";
                classVariable = Level005Activity.class;
                break;
        }

        String fileName = "record_" + level_selected + ".json";

        // Get the JSON Object from the data
        JSONObject parents = parseJSONData(fileName);

        // This will store all the values inside "best_move and time" in an element string
        try {
            best_move = parents.getInt("best_move");
            best_time = parents.getString("best_time");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
           // e.printStackTrace();
        }

        levelName.setText("Level " + level_selected.substring(5));
        bestMove.setText("Best Move: " + best_move);
        bestTime.setText("Best Time: " + best_time);

        playBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        classVariable);
                startActivity(i);
                finish();
            }
        });

    }

    public JSONObject parseJSONData(String file) {
        String JSONString = null;
        JSONObject jsonObject = null;
        try {
            // Open the inputStream to the file
            FileInputStream fin = openFileInput(file);

            int sizeOfJSONFile = fin.available();

            // array that will store all the data
            byte[] bytes = new byte[sizeOfJSONFile];

            // reading data into the array from the file
            fin.read(bytes);

            // close the input stream
            fin.close();

            JSONString = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(JSONString);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } catch (JSONException x) {
            x.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return jsonObject;
    }
}
```

choose_level.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="You have not finish any level yet."
        android:id="@+id/no_level_finished"
        android:visibility="gone"
        />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/level_completed"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/level001"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="@drawable/smiley"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/level002"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="@drawable/heaven_full"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/level001"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/level003"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="@drawable/smiley"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/level002"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/level004"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"

            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/level003"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/level005"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"

            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/level004"
            android:visibility="gone"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/level_desc"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/level_completed"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/level_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

       <TextView
            android:id="@+id/best_move"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/level_name"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/best_time"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/best_move"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/playBtn"
            android:layout_below="@+id/best_time"
            android:text="Play Level"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

DDMS Heap tab

[image]

How do I read the DDMS and make use of it to find the problem which is taking so much memory ? Please kindly let me know if there is anything else needed to debug this such as allocation tracker or the threads tab in DDMS. Thank you for all help, really appreciate it.

Comment: Did you find these resources? http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-memory.html  https://youtu.be/P--rg1o7Cz4?list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc9CBxr3BVjPTPoDPLdPIFCE

Comment: yes that is the manual on how to use it, but I get confused trying to connect it to my project, so if anyone got a better approach at looking for the faults, will be a great help. Thank you anyway, will watch the youtube in a moment.

Answer (score 0):

In my point using DDMS is hard and inefficient for developers to detect the app's memory leak.
I recommend you use the Square's [memory leak detect library](https://corner.squareup.com/2015/05/leak-canary.html).This library is specialized for detecting java and android's memory leak and you know more from this project's [github page](https://github.com/square/leakcanary).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, looking into it now.